# How can I get direct keyboard input in cpp? (cross platform)

Tags: c++, keyboard, cross-platform

I want to be able to control the program with direct input without pauseing the program and without waiting for the user to press enter.

I can currently achieve this with **kbhit**, but it appears that is a windows only solution.

**Ncurses** also looks promising, but it appears to only work for linux (and maybe mac?  Is unix the structure mac is based on?).

I especially like the **kbhit** for it's simplicity, and I like the tool set that **ncurses**, but I was wondering if there was a simple, easy way to get something running cross-platform without having to maintain essentially 2-3 versions of the code using these different tools?

Comment: There is no such thing as universal cross platform. You must list the platforms you are interested in supporting.

Comment: just the big three, windows, linux and mac would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.  I'm trying to do many things that cpp was never intended to do by default, so the options are to use libraries like allegro, or, in my case it turns out what I needed was a game engine.  I found that Unity with text mesh pro can do everything I need it to.  It comes with an entire input management system.